# focusrow is not working the first time extjs4.2 grid is loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have a extjs grid on the popup, which has to show a row selected and focused when the popup is open. It doesn't show selected the first time but If I close the popup and open it again it works perfect.

```
function CreateClientGrid()
{
if ( clientGrid === null )
    {
    var grid_inp,
        columns = [], column,
        index, i =0;

         var clienttype = $('#clienttype').val();
      if(clienttype == 1)
    {
        grid_data = GetAffiliateGridData();
       }
       else if(clienttype == 0)
       {
         grid_data = GetClientGridData();

       }
       else if(clienttype == 2)
       {
         grid_data = GetAdvertiserGridData();
       }

    $( "#client_grid" ).keydown(function(e)
    {
        var ret = KeyCheck ( e, clientGrid );
        return ( ret );
    });



    // Prepare columns for grid
    for ( index in grid_data.keys )
        {
        column = {
            text        : grid_data['values'][index],
            dataIndex   : grid_data['keys'][index]['name'],
            flex        : 1,
            sortable    : true,
            editor      : {
                allowBlank : true
            }
        };

        columns[i++] = column;

        }

    grid_inp = {
        renderTo: 'client-grid',
        frame: true,
        id: 'clientGrid',
        autoScroll: true,
        width: 375,
        height: 228,
         plugins: {
                    ptype: 'bufferedrenderer',
                    trailingBufferZone: 40, // Keep 40 rows rendered in the table behind scroll
                    leadingBufferZone: 80 // Keep 80 rows rendered in the table ahead of scroll
                },
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        },
        selType: 'rowmodel',
        store: affiliateStore,
        columns: columns,
        columnLines: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        dockedItems: []
    };
    clientGrid = Ext.create('Ext.ux.LiveSearchGridPanel', grid_inp );
      if(Number(selected)!= 0)
    {

      console.log(selected);

    clientGrid.getSelectionModel().select(Number(selected));
   clientGrid.getView().focusRow(Number(selected),800);
   //clientGrid.getPlugin('bufferedrenderer').scrollTo(20);

    }
    }

    if(Number(selected)!= 0)
    {

      console.log(selected);

    clientGrid.getSelectionModel().select(Number(selected));
    clientGrid.getView().focusRow(Number(selected),800);
    //clientGrid.getPlugin('bufferedrenderer').scrollTo(20);

    }

// Clear the search field in the grid toolbar
clientGrid.down('textfield[name=searchField]').setValue('');
}
```

what is the problem and the solution?

Comment: This may be an issue with the timing of the grid rendering and your attempt  to select/focus the row.  Can you try attaching an event to the grid to select/focus the row after it has rendered, to make sure that code executes after the grid is ready?

Comment: I tried to add delay also, but that also doesn't work